# ISO 9660 standard and bits about volume date

Tags: iso, dvd, iso9660

For some time I am wondering and searching through Internet looking for answer about iso files that are written on DVD or CD discs (ISO 9660 standard as far as I know).

I have found this paper http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~varun/cs315p/iso9660.pdf about this standard. At page 45 there is tabel describing what is set on which bit. Two rows are quite interesting for me: Volume Creation Date and Time and Volume Experiation Date and Time. If I am getting it right there is a possibility that I can make CD that won't run after date that I will set at expiriation date, or is it other thing.

Also does any of you ever use those bits. I was looking for something different in this paper, but it is quite interesting and I would like to dig into this topic, so maybe you have got also any extra materials about it.

Thank you for answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell this MAY have something to do with backup media and backup solutions to know when the backed up data has expired. And the archive slot is now available for re-use or from when it MUST-NOT be used as the backup is past it's expiry date.

This is quite common for other backup media like tape backups. Various software solutions require the need to specify expiry dates to know when to re-use tapes and when to generate warnings and alerts based on the solution's own implementation.

I believe this is a compatibility field to allow large scale systems to be able to replace legacy systems with  iso9660 images (CDs etc).

I don't think this is actually enforced by most of the software that consumers use at the moment.

Even in the olden days the software using the backup media will have an override parameter to ensure that expired volumes/archives can actually be used by a forced manual override.

Hope this helps.